# is_prime function fails when testing 121, don't know why

Tags: python, primes, modulo

I'm trying to write a function that takes an integer x and returns True if prime, False if not. It works fine except for when testing the number 121 and I can't figure out why. Here's my code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x%i == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

When checking 121, it seems to skip over `if x%i == 0:`, because `121%11` is 0, but it doesn't return as False. Am I missing something obvious here? I appreciate any help I can get, thanks. Oh and I'm working with Python 2.7

Comment: @VincentShowcaseWorkshop Not really. All answers to the question you linked use trial division, which is about the worst way to check whether a number is composite or prime.

Comment: Deleted my comment then to not put him on the wrong way :) Cheers for your comment.

Answer (score 8):

You almost have it. You just need one tiny change

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x%i == 0:
                return False
        return True
```

The problem that you are facing is due to the fact that you don't allow your loop to finish checking all numbers before it returns

Consider the first few iterations when  you run your code on 121:

The function says:

- Is `x` smaller than 2?
- - No. Go on
- Is `x` exactly 2?
- - No. Go on
- for all the numbers, 2 through x-1 (`for i in range(2,x)`)
- - right now `i` is 2
- - is 121%2 exactly 0?
- - - no. Go on
- - else (well, 121%2 was not 0, so I go in here)
- - - return True <-- Oops!

So what you need to do, is finish running through all those numbers in that for loop, before deciding to return, which is what my fix does.

Of course (as Joran Beasley notes), you could exploit the knowledge that no divisor of any number is is larger than its square-root. So you just need to check up to the square-root of the number itself:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x<2:
        return False
    if x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for i in xrange(2, int(sqrt(x))+1):
            if not n%i:
                return False
        return True
```

Comment: its worth noting that he should probably end his range at int(sqrt(x))

Comment: Oh true! and I'd take it further to `range(3, int(sqrt(x))` since he's already testing for 2

Comment: but hes not testing for divisibility by 2... unless Im missing it

Comment: wow this is it and the logic is sound. i also really like changing the range to range(3, int(sqrt)). Good stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Yeah... nvm. I misinterpreted something. Went back and checked it out. You're right

Comment: oh an I was wrong `int(sqrt(x))+1` should be stopping point  or it will return True for 4

Comment: If you do check for divisibility by 2 first then you can use `xrange(3, int(sqrt(x)+1), 2)`, which is half as many trial divisions. Or check for 2, 3, first and then do `xrange(6, int(sqrt(x)+2), 6)`, but in each loop test both `i-1` and `i+1` instead of `i`. And so on with rapidly diminishing returns.